# Convert a 2^8 bit representation to a BigInteger on Go

Tags: go, math

I have the following code snippet here that I want to convert to Go.

```
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        b = b.add(BigInteger.ONE.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(bytes[i] & 0xff)).shiftLeft(i * 8));
    }
    return b;
```

My converted code to Go below:

```
//return utils.BytesToBigInteger(bytes)
b := BigInteger_ZERO()
for i, val := range bytes {
    el := (&big.Int{}).SetUint64(uint64(uint8(val & 0xff))) // & 0xff)
    one := BigInteger_ONE()
    one = one.Mul(one, el)
    b = b.Add(b, el.Lsh(el, uint(i*8)))
}

return b
```

It seems that the result is still not consistent though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't just use `BigInteger.valueOf(1 << 8)`?

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to convert code from one language to another is rarely a good idea. Write the function in Go. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/big"
)

func BytesToBigInteger(b []byte) *big.Int {
    return new(big.Int).SetBytes(b)
}

func main() {
    b := []byte{1, 1}
    i := BytesToBigInteger(b)
    fmt.Println(i, uint16(1<<8+1))
    b = []byte{255, 255, 255, 255}
    i = BytesToBigInteger(b)
    fmt.Println(i, uint32(math.MaxUint32))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/LWzDtr2pkom

Output:

```
257 257
4294967295 4294967295
```